# backup failed .../.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found in backup on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: backup, deja-dup

[image]the restore of the entire backup from the 'Settings' app, works fine, but when it get to 'verifying backup...' using button 'back up now' i get the error message :

> Could not restore ‘~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata’: File not found   in backup

regards,

Comment: Please add screen shots, and steps for replication will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to : https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1217959
(It's a big mess)

This bug is known for about 3 years now!

We know this problem happen when you symlink "~/.cache/deja-dup", but maybe there is other cases.

If you are in this case, you can try to delete your symlink, and replace it by : `sudo mount --rbind /run/media/daboross/external/deja-dup-cache ~/.cache/deja-dup`.

Or maybe create an empty `~/.cache/deja-dup/metadata` file.

If none of these solutions works, I don't know, nobody knows :)